# Prove that $f(C(R)) = C(S)$.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

> If $f :R \to S$ is an isomorphism from ring $R$ to ring $S$, prove  that $f(C(R)) = C(S)$. i.e., that $f(C(R))$ is the
> center of $S$.

- Take $r_1 \in C(R)$ and $r \in R$ then, $f(r_1r)=f(rr_1)$ as $r_1 \in C(R)$
- Since $f$  homomorphism  $f(r_1)f(r)=f(r)f(r_1)$
- This follows $f(r_1) \in C(S)$. Since $f$ is one to one and onto each element in $C(R)$ there is a unique element in $C(S)$
- Therefore  $f(C(R)) = C(S)$.

Can anyone please verify my answer? If it is wrong please correct me!!

Comment: What are $R$ and $S$?

Comment: I'd mark it 3/10. I see a confused proof of $f(C(R))\subseteq C(S)$ but nothing about the reverse inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show two things:

1. $f\big(C(R)\big)\subseteq C(S)$, and
2. $C(S)\subseteq f\big(C(R)\big)$.

The center $C(S)$ is defined as those elements $s\in S$ such that for all $t\in S$, $st=ts$.  You need to be careful about the `for all' bit.  To do this for statement #1 above, start with an arbitrary element $t\in S$, and show that anything in $f\big(C(R)\big)$ commutes with that $t$.  Statement #2 requires a similar style of argument.